# Using select() for timing out a socket

Tags: c, sockets, select

I am attempting to make a simple [port scanner](https://github.com/SpinCloud/Chevron/tree/devel) in C, and am finally at the final stage. I wrote a simple function to connect to a server on a port, and should timeout if the port is closed. I have the following testcase:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "idiot.\n");
    }

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0);

    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags);

    if(sock < 0) {
        perror("socket()");
    }

    struct hostent *server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if (server == NULL) {
        perror("gethostbyname()");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    bzero((char*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy(server->h_addr, (char*)&server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));

    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("connecting()");
    }

    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int retval;

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(sock, &rfds);

    tv.tv_sec = 3;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    retval = select(sock+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if (retval == -1)
        perror("select()");
    else if (retval)
        printf("port is open.\n");
    else
        printf("port is closed.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is, any port I pass it, is reported as open. For example:

```
[nchambers@shell:~/SpinCloud/Chevron] [devel]$ ./testcase localhost 22 # sshd actually runs on this machine, so its correct
connecting(): Operation now in progress
port is open.
[nchambers@shell:~/SpinCloud/Chevron] [devel]$ telnet localhost 22
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
^]

telnet> quit
Connection closed.
[nchambers@shell:~/SpinCloud/Chevron] [devel]$ ./testcase localhost 80 # but no webserver
connecting(): Operation now in progress
port is open.
[nchambers@shell:~/SpinCloud/Chevron] [devel]$ telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
[nchambers@shell:~/SpinCloud/Chevron] [devel]$
```

Answer (score 4):

The fact that `select` reports something as "readable" or "writable" only means that an attempt to `read`/`write` will not block. It does not imply anything about what the *result* of that `read`/`write` will be.

Note: also, you need to distinguish the case when `connect` returns `EINPROGRESS` (and poll for writability in that case) from other failures. (though maybe you could use `TCP_KEEPCNT` or `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT` instead? But that wouldn't work if you used `getaddrinfo` like you're supposed to and tried *all* of the addresses potentially at once, but with a delay between each)

Also, you should seriously consider using one of the newer alternatives, at least `poll` (which is POSIX) if not somemthing system-specific like `epoll` or `kqueue`.

Answer (score 2):

You are opening a non-blocking request.  When you call connect(), it returns `EINPROGRESS`, or "operation is now in progress", as described in the [manpage for connect()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html):

```
          The socket is nonblocking and the connection cannot be
          completed immediately.  It is possible to select(2) or poll(2)
          for completion by selecting the socket for writing.  After
          select(2) indicates writability, use getsockopt(2) to read the
          SO_ERROR option at level SOL_SOCKET to determine whether
          connect() completed successfully (SO_ERROR is zero) or
          unsuccessfully (SO_ERROR is one of the usual error codes
          listed here, explaining the reason for the failure).
```

You should be checking the `errno` value on connect().  Also, a nonnegative `select` return does not necessarily mean the port is open on the server you're testing.

As an aside, the code you've posted is not, in general, handling errors well.  From the very first `if(argc != 3) {`, you don't return but just print a message.  If you were to run your code without three inputs, it'd display the error, but then continue execution (which would probably end up with a seg fault).

I'd encourage you to spend more time researching synchronous vs asynchronous i/o and actually connecting to ports before assuming they're open.

Comment: @DTSCode Reading all the man pages is a great start, there are a *lot* of them.